# Spring Batch: Using executions.ftl for my custom controller

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I am working with Spring Batch, and I have added a new functionality to filter job executions. What I've done is create a new Controller:

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class FilteredJobExecutionResource {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("filteredJobExecutionService")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private FilteredJobExecutionService filteredJobExecutionService;

    private TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

    public FilteredJobExecutionResource() {
        super();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/jobs/executions.*/filter/{filter}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ModelAttribute("jobExecutions")
    Collection<JobExecutionInfo> list(ModelMap model, @PathVariable("filter") String filter,
                                      @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int startJobExecution,
                                      @RequestParam(defaultValue = "20") int pageSize) throws Exception {

        int total = filteredJobExecutionService.countJobExecutions(filter);
        TableUtils.addPagination(model, total, startJobExecution, pageSize, "JobExecution");

        Collection<JobExecutionInfo> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (JobExecution jobExecution : filteredJobExecutionService.listJobExecutionsByFilter(filter, startJobExecution, pageSize)) {
            result.add(new JobExecutionInfo(jobExecution, timeZone));
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

This class, is very similar to Spring Batch `JobExecutionController`, but adding a `PathVariable`, filter. The problem I am facing is that I want my controller to use the existing json/executions.ftl like `JobExecutionController` does, but I am getting the following error:

> Could not resolve view with name 'jobs/executions.json/filter/662' in
>   servlet with name 'RESTServlet'

Any idea how could I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I found a partial solution:

`<bean name="jobs/executions.json/filter/662" parent="standard.json">
  <property name="attributes">
   <props merge="true">
    <prop key="body">/manager/jobs/json/executions.ftl</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>
`

But it only works for a request which filter value is 662. Any way to do it for any value?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution adding this to my application context:

```
<bean name="jobs/executions.json/filter" parent="standard.json">
    <property name="attributes">
        <props merge="true">
            <prop key="body">/manager/jobs/json/executions.ftl</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But, I had to change the @PathVariable filter to @RequestParam:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/jobs/executions.*/filter" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ModelAttribute("jobExecutions")
    Collection<JobExecutionInfo> list(ModelMap model, @RequestParam("value") String value,@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int startJobExecution,@RequestParam(defaultValue = "20") int pageSize)
```

Any idea how to get this working setting filter as a @PathVariable?